"OR" condition between two different labels in PromQL
I am using PromQL. I have different labels that represent the same thing for different environments. For example:
http_server_request{env=~"$env"}
It works fine for the dev environment, but for prod, the label that represents the environment is "environment", so the query will be:
http_server_request{environment=~"$env"}
I want one query that will give me data points for all different environments, something like this:
http_server_request{environment=~"$env" or env=~"$env"}
Is there any way to write a query like this?
I tried to write two different queries. They work, but this approach make the entire dashboard much more complicated.

http_server_request{environment=~"$env"} or http_server_request{env=~"$env"}
